# Cordova app does not have internet

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have created a website using jQuery mobile that connects to a php web service that I created to get data.The website works fine both on the desktop browsers and on the mobile browsers.
I have built the project for both android and iOS and they cannot retrieve any data from the internet.

All Ajax requests made to my domain where the server is hosted are failing.
One of the request is:

```
var getSchedule = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://www.lefkatis.com/nba/APIData.php",
        data: {"action": "schedule"}
    });
getSchedule.done(function (data) {
    console.log('Schedule Loaded');
});
getSchedule.fail(function ( getSchedule, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

The working website of this project that uses the same code is [here](http://www.lefaktis.com/nba)

Please feel free to ask me any additional information that might help as this is my first stackoverflow post.

Bear in mind that this is my first cordova app

Answer (score 2):

In Cordova 5 and newer by default they will all fail unless you set an appropriate Content Security Policy meta tag in your index.html - Cordova will block all Ajax requests otherwise.

You can do this by adding something like this to your page in the head element in order to allow access to any server:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src *">
```

Or you can limit connect-src to just the server(s) you want to access using space separated list like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src https://www.lefkatis.com">
```

There's a detailed blog post explaining this, and other considerations for iOS 9 specifically [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).  As your server is running an SSL connection you should be OK with just the Content Security Policy for iOS 9 and would not need an App Transport Security exception configuring in your project.

Comment: I am testing it on both android and iOS and its the same problem. This did not fix it :/
any other suggestions?